# How to structure one of many commands in yargs?

Tags: yargs

I have read the yargs documetation multiple times, but can't figure out this one. Here are my requirements:

- My CLI should provide two commands: `cmd1` and `cmd2`.
- The user must specify one of these two commands, otherwise the CLI must print a help message and exit.

This is my attempt:

```
async function main() {
  await yargs(process.argv.slice(2))
    .command('cmd1', 'Command 1', {}, () => console.log('Executing command1'))
    .command('cmd2', 'Command 2', {}, () => console.log('Executing command2'))
    .help().argv;
}
```

Following commands work as expected:

```
my-cli cmd1   # prints "Executing command1"
my-cli cmd2   # prints "Executing command2"
```

However following commands quit silently:

```
my-cli
my-cli cmd3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can add `.strict()`: https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-strictenabledtrue

Comment: Thank you so much, @Raptor. Refining this a bit, the combination that worked best for me was `.strictCommands()` + `.demandCommand(1)`. Would you mind adding an "official" answer?

Comment: Done, thanks! Nice to hear that it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation and the refine of OP, the correct `yarg` code handling undefined arguments is as follow:

```
async function main() {
  await yargs(process.argv.slice(2))
    .command('cmd1', 'Command 1', {}, () => console.log('Executing command1'))
    .command('cmd2', 'Command 2', {}, () => console.log('Executing command2'))
    .strictCommands()
    .demandCommand()
    .help().argv;
}
```

- `strictCommands()`: accepts only defined commands (i.e. does not accept undefined command like `cmd3`) [Documentation](https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-strictcommandsenabledtrue)
- `demandCommand()`: accepts minimum 1 argument (i.e. does not accept a command with no argument); 1 is the default value of minimum; can also add `max` option to constraint to exactly 1 argument by `demandCommand(1, 1)` [Documentation](https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-demandcommandmin1-minmsg)

Comment: Thank you, @Raptor. The yargs API is very wide and gets difficult to spot exactly what's needed. Your answer was a big help.